# What is the proper way to handle RabbitMQ events in a windows service?

Tags: c#, rabbitmq, windows-services

I've never created a Windows Service before and am now being asked to do so.  I need to create a service that handles events raised by a RabbitMQ consumer.

In my mind, once you hook up the event handler, you need something to "keep the service alive"; otherwise the service ends and your handlers go away.  I've seen code samples that seem to indicate you put the app into a while(true) loop -- which doesn't feel right.

This is what I have so far

```cs
public class MyWorker : BackgroundService
{
   protected override async Task ExcecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
   {
       var _factory = new ConnectionFactory() {
          HostName = "localhost",
          UserName = "guest",
          Password = "guest"
       };

      var _connection = _factory.CreateConnection();
      var _channel = _connection.CreateModel();

      _factory.DispatchConsumersAsync = true;
      var _consumer = new AsyncEventingBasicConsumer(_channel);
      _consumer.Received += async (sender, ea) => {
          // Code to handle queue item here
          _channel.BasicAck(ea.DeliveryTag,true);
          await Task.Yield();
      };
      var tag = _consumer.BasicConsume("MyQueue",false,_consumer);

      while(!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested){};

      _consumer.BasicCancel(tag);
}
```

Is this the proper way to go about this in a Service?  Will that `while` loop burn up CPU cycles?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your code will work just fine. I took the time to expand a bit on it -

```
namespace rabbitmq_backgroundservice;

using RabbitMQ.Client;
using RabbitMQ.Client.Events;

public class Worker : BackgroundService
{
    private const string _queueName = "MyQueue";
    private readonly TimeSpan _stoppingCheckInterval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);
    private readonly ILogger<Worker> _logger;
    private readonly IConnection _connection;
    private readonly IModel _channel;
    private readonly EventingBasicConsumer _consumer;
    private readonly string _consumerTag;

    public Worker(ILogger<Worker> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;

        var factory = new ConnectionFactory {
            HostName = "localhost",
            UserName = "guest",
            Password = "guest"
        };

        _connection = factory.CreateConnection();
        _channel = _connection.CreateModel();

        _channel.QueueDeclare(_queueName, true, true);

        _consumer = new EventingBasicConsumer(_channel);
        _consumer.Received += ReceivedHandler;

        _consumerTag = _channel.BasicConsume(_queueName, false, _consumer);
    }

    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        using (_connection)
        using (_channel)
        {
            while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                _logger.LogInformation("Worker running at: {time}", DateTimeOffset.Now);
                await Task.Delay(_stoppingCheckInterval, stoppingToken);
            }

            _logger.LogInformation("Worker STOPPING at: {time}", DateTimeOffset.Now);
            _channel.BasicCancel(_consumerTag);
        }
    }

    private void ReceivedHandler(object? sender, BasicDeliverEventArgs ea)
    {
        var tag = ea.DeliveryTag;
        _logger.LogInformation("Received message. tag: {tag}  at: {time}", tag, DateTimeOffset.Now);
        _channel.BasicAck(tag, false);
    }
}
```

Repository here:

https://github.com/lukebakken/rabbitmq-backgroundservice

I used this reference:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/windows-service